# How do I rectify these PHP warnings and errors when trying to connect to Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: php, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm currently trying to establish a connection file through php to my Oracle SQL Developer database.

**This is my connection file code:**

```
<?php
// This scripts sets up PHP environment variables to display all errors on 
the screen
// and then connects to an oracle database

// Send PHP errors to the screen (should always be off for live systems)
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// Set PHP error reporting level to report all errors.
error_reporting(E_ALL);

echo "<style type='text/css'> p {font-size: x-large} </style>";

// CONNECT TO ORACLE STUDENT ACCOUNT AT HALLAM
// Display 'connecting' message
echo "<p>Connecting . . . </p>";

// Set up variables for connection
$con_hostname = 'homepages.shu.ac.uk:1521/shu11g.shu.ac.uk';
// CHANGE THE LINES BELOW TO ADD YOUR LOGIN DETAILS !!!
$con_username = 'B009';
$con_password = 'J123df';


// Connect to the database.  $conn is a variable of type 'resource', and is 
the connection handle. 
// It returns a connection identifier, or FALSE (if it fails to connect)
$conn = oci_connect($con_username, $con_password, $con_hostname);

if (!$conn) {
$e = oci_error();
trigger_error(htmlentities($e['message'], ENT_QUOTES), E_USER_ERROR);
}
else { echo "<p> . . . Connected</p>";}
?>
```

As you can see I've defined the specific variables needed to connect the file to the database within the developer but when I try to run the file to test that the connection is working I get two warnings and one fatal error. I'm unsure on the specifics of the errors in question so could anyone here point out why I'm getting these errors and how it is I can go about fixing them?

[image]

Comment: Your PHP script and [SQL Developer](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/sql-developer/overview/index.html) are both clients that connect to the database. I'm not sure what you mean by connecting to Oracle SQL Developer. Did you just mean connecting to Oracle?

Answer (score 0):

As the error states, you are missing ORACLE_HOME and LD_LIBRARY_PATH on your system. These are paths defined on your system that link to resources, and the Oracle Connection code you have written requires the Oracle database client software to be installed on your system, and to know where it is.

Have you checked the IBM documentation? [IBM Documentation on adding ORACLE_HOME to your system](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSFUEU_7.3.0/com.ibm.swg.ba.cognos.op_installation_guide.7.3.0.doc/t_camphor_setting_environment_variables_ora.html)